# How to add Dependencies in React Native Project

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, react-native, dependency-management

How can i add Dependencies to the react-native project?
That the Dependencies take size in the main apk if yes than how to reduce the size of apk?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting with React Native I wouldn't worry too much ahead of time on reducing your project size if you need to use a specific dependency.

If the dependency helps you do something in a much more efficient way then use it.  Also use it if you need that dependency to access a specific feature, obviously.

To use a dependency you can do the following (this is assuming you are using Expo managed workflow which I highly suggest if you are just learning).

I'll use lodash as an example as it is a popular utility library.

`npm install lodash`
         or
`yarn add lodash`

you can then use the lodash library with the following inside your project:

`import _ from 'lodash'`

Then you'll have access to the functions by using `_.**insert method here**`
You can also destructure a specific function off the lodash library with typical destructuring syntax: `import { indexOf } from 'lodash'`